# Figuring out the algorithmic complexity of my Program in Big-O Notation

Tags: c++, binary, big-o, time-complexity

I have created this program that will do a binary search on a order list the user enters, and outputs the desired value they want to search for in that list.  My problem is I have to find the algorithmic complexity in Big-O Notation for each part of my code then do the Time Complexity of it, however, I am not great at figuring out the Big-O notation.  If possible could you explain how I could do it, etc.  Here's my code and I have tried already to figure the algorithmic complexity  for some lines, if I did something wrong please correct me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


int binarySearch(vector<double> uservector, int, int);


int main()
{
int size;  // O(1)
int i;  //O(1)
int desirednum;  // O(1)

cout << "How many values do you want to enter: ";  // O(1)
cin >> size;  // O(1)
vector<double> uservector(size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> uservector[i];
}

cout << "What value are you looking for: ";  // O(1)
cin >> desirednum;  // O(1)

int location = binarySearch(uservector, size, desirednum);  

if( location > -1)
    cout << "The value " << desirednum << " was found at index " << location   << endl;  // O(1)
else 
    cout << "The value was not found in the list. \n";  // O(1)

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int binarySearch(vector<double> uservector, int size, int value)
{
int low, mid, high;

low = 0;
high = size - 1;
while(low <= high)
{
    mid = ((low + high) / 2);
    if(value == uservector[mid])
    {
        return
            mid;
    }
    else if(value > uservector[mid])
        low = mid + 1;
    else
        high = mid - 1;
}
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right, to some degree. To some other, you don't.

```
int main()
{
int size;  // O(1)
int i;  //O(1)
int desirednum;  // O(1)
```

These aren't instructions, they are declarations. They don't take run time at all.

```
cout << "How many values do you want to enter: ";  // O(1)
```

You shouldn't be counting things that happen prior to the start of your algorithm at all.

```
cin >> size;  // O(1)
vector<double> uservector(size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> uservector[i];
}

cout << "What value are you looking for: ";  // O(1)
cin >> desirednum;  // O(1)
```

You shouldn't be counting things that happen prior to the start of your algorithm at all.

```
int location = binarySearch(uservector, size, desirednum);  

if( location > -1)
    cout << "The value " << desirednum << " was found at index " << location   << endl;  // O(1)
else 
    cout << "The value was not found in the list. \n";  // O(1)

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Ok, so here starts the part you actually want to have a complexity for.

```
int binarySearch(vector<double> uservector, int size, int value)
{
int low, mid, high;

low = 0;
high = size - 1;
while(low <= high)
{
    mid = ((low + high) / 2);
    if(value == uservector[mid])
    {
        return
            mid;
    }
    else if(value > uservector[mid])
        low = mid + 1;
    else
        high = mid - 1;
}
    return -1;
}
```

You're halving the distance to your target each iteration, giving you a log2(N) complexity.

Comment: Might I suggest subscripting base "2" in "log2(N)" for clarity?

Comment: You might, but it doesn't really matter; log2(x) is just log10(x) / log10(2), which is a constant factor, so this is all O(log(N))